# Neural network learning algorithm with heaviside/step-function

Tags: algorithm, neural-network

Is there any implementation (or straightforward description) of a training algorithm for feed-forward neural networks which doesn't use a sigmoid or linear squash-function, but a non-differentiable one, such as the heaviside-function?

I already found a [paper on such an algorithm](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel3/1059/7404/00298832.pdf?arnumber=298832), but no according implementation, which I find bewildering, as it seems to me, there should be something out.

Any hints?

Comment: Just to double-check; Nothing on the following page helps you right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function

Comment: Not directly. The wiikpage says that backpropagation doesn't work with heaviside step functions. So what I’m looking for is thus: how are these networks trained instead, is there any implementation? I should also mention that I am dealing with a multilayer (at least one hidden layer) perceptron.

Comment: So specifically, you want an activation function which is not differentiable?

Comment: Yes, more specifically: the heaviside activation function, just as in the biological analog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Backpropagation will not work with the heavyside function because its derivate is zero in all the domain, except for the point zero, where it is infinite. That is, the derivative of the heavyside function is the [Dirac delta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).

The consequence of this is that there is no change for any value other than zero and no progress can be made. At the point zero, the derivate is infinite, so the step is not manageable either.

You can find online an [implementation for this function in Java](http://franck.fleurey.free.fr/NeuralNetwork/javadoc/NeuralNetwork/HeavisideActivationFunction.html), but I still don't think that it is a good idea to use it. If you increase the gama power in the sigmoid function, it becomes a very decent approximation of the heavyside function with the added benefit of differentiability.

Check [this paper](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/egbhuang/TCASII-ELM-Threshold-Network.pdf) at see if it has any information that might be of help to you.

Comment: Thanks, the paper is helpful and there is an implementation for the ELM methods (which have other shortcomings though). The java-implementation is not particularily helpful as it uses unmodified backpropagation (which as you state does not work). So I guess, I’ll have to implement the method of the IEEE paper mentioned in my question myself…

Comment: Backpropagation will compensate any change of the slope of the activation function e.g. sigmoid, by changing the connection weight, so that is not a solution unless the network connection is such as to have a fixed weight.

Comment: the link `this paper` does not work anymore -- did you mean http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.102.4371 ?