# Matlab activation function for values 0 and 1

Tags: matlab, neural-network, activation

I am working on an artificial neural network. I want to implement it in Matlab, but I am unable to find a proper activation function. I need a step function because my output is either 0 or 1. is there any function in Matlab that can be used for this kind of output. Also, I want the reverse function of the same activation function. `logsig` and `tansig` are not working for me.

Comment: Can you be more specific , what you really want ? 0 and 1 with any function ?

Comment: I don't really get the question, but there is no reverse function for a step function.

Comment: What do you mean by "the reverse function"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heaviside did not work for me.. i finally normalized my data between 1 and -1 and then applied tansig.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Both `tansig` and `logsig` are part of the Neural Network Toolbox as the online documentation makes clear. So, if `which tansig` returns nothing, then you don't have that toolbox (or at least don't have a version current enough to contain that function). However, both of these functions are extremely simple, and the documentation even gives you the formulae under the "Algorithms" section: [`tansig`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/tansig.html#f8-3720965), [`logsig`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/logsig.html#f8-500779). Both can be implemented as a one line anonymous function if you wanted.

If your question is actually about how to produce a [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), Matlab has [`heaviside`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/heaviside.html) (it's part of the Symbolic Math toolbox but a pure numeric version is included – type `edit heaviside` to see the simple code). However, note that using such a non-differentiable function is problematic for some types of neural networks as [this StackOverflow question and answer addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046173/neural-network-learning-algorithm-with-heaviside-step-function).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. logsig and tansig gives fine results but in my case i want an activation function that gives output either 0 or 1. i have already tried heavside , but i think it gives 0 for negative values and 1 for positive values whereas my output ranges from 0 to 1 so i need something else. In neural network theory the required function is called STEP  but i am unable to find the matlab alternative.

Comment: @Mehak: I'm confused. The Heaviside function *is* the step function. And it does exactly what you say you need by giving an output that is either 0 or 1. If you want the transition to occur at a different value, just shift the input: `heaviside(x-a)` for a step that begins at `a`. Maybe you're thinking of the [boxcar function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxcar_function)?

Comment: can you please explain how to use heaviside for following conditions

if x <= 0.2, heaviside(x)=0
   x > 0.2, heaviside(x)=1 

i also need the inverse of the same activation function, what is inverse of heaviside?

Comment: @Mehak: This is really basic addition and subtraction: `y = 1-heaviside(x-0.2)`. Because of the definition of the Heaviside function `y = 0.5` when `x` is exactly `0.2` (If you want to define it differently, write your own version). The Heaviside function has an inverse, but this inverse is not a function because the Heaviside function is [piecewise constant](http://www.chilimath.com/algebra/advanced/inverse/inverse-of-constant-function.html). Draw it out on paper yourself. I told you in my answer that this sort of function is problematic as an activation function for neural networks.

Comment: The best you could do in faking an inverse function would be to choose arbitrary values for `x` for the two possible values of `y`. So something like: `if y == 0.5; x = 0; elseif y == 1; x = 1; elseif y == 0; x = -1; else; x = NaN; end`. But instead of `1` and `-1` I could have chosen `0` for both too. This probably won't work.